# Django forms checkbox selection does not work

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a Django form with a check box for "Accept terms of service" but if I check it or not my app blocks the request with the message "you have to accept our Terms of service".

Here is my code:

forms.py

```
class ProfileModelForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['u_fullname',
              'u_job',
              'u_country',
              'u_email',
              'u_terms',
              ]

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ProfileModelForm, self).clean()
        u_fullname = cleaned_data.get('u_fullname')
        u_job = cleaned_data.get('u_job')
        u_country = cleaned_data.get('u_country')
        u_email = cleaned_data.get('u_email')
        u_terms = cleaned_data.get('u_terms')
        if not u_terms:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please read and accept our Terms of Service")

        if not u_fullname and not u_job and not u_country and not u_terms:
            raise forms.ValidationError('You have to write something!')

        return cleaned_data
```

Field u_terms is a Booleanfield in my model.

the views.py:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'user_reg' in request.POST:
        form = ProfileModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            #Create user and get the id
            n_user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST['u_email'],
                                            email=request.POST['u_email'],
                                            password=request.POST['u_password'])
            instance.user = User.objects.get(id=n_user.id)
            instance.u_profile = 'U'
            print("TERMS-->",request.POST['u_terms'])
            instance.save()
            return  # Put return here
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Error")
            #form = ProfileModelForm()

        return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})

    elif 'register' in request.POST:
        pass
    elif 'company' in request.POST:
        pass
```

and the html  template part related to my checkbox:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 no-pdd">
    <div class="checky-sec st2">
        <div class="fgt-sec">
            <input type="checkbox" name="cc" id="c2" value={{ form.u_terms }}>
            <label for="c2">
                <span></span>
            </label>
            <small>Yes, I understand and agree to the workwise Terms & Conditions.</small>
        </div><!--fgt-sec end-->
    </div>
</div>
```

I imagine the problem is in my html part but I don't know how can I manage boolean fields from checkbox.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Instead of `<input name="cc" ...>` use `{{ form.u_terms }}` that should render the checkbox. The problem is your input has the wrong "name" attribute so the value is submitted as `request.POST['cc']` not `request.POST['u_terms']` which your form expects. You can check that by printing `request.POST` or looking at the request in your browser debug tools.

Comment: Alternatively, if you really need to render the <input> tag yourself, use `name="{{ form.u_terms.html_name }}"` as the name attribute. And remove the value attribute, if you look at the source code in your browser you'll see it's not what you want. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#attributes-of-boundfield) are all the attributes of a form's `BoundField`.

Answer (score 3):

The "name" attribute of your `<input>` element does not match the POST attribute expected by your form: `cc` != `u_terms`.

You can solve this in two ways:

- Use `{{ form.u_terms }}` to render the entire `<input>` tag. Note that you put that into the value attribute, which is wrong (look at the source code inside your browser, you'll see what I mean).

  ```
  {{ form.u_terms }}
  {{ form.u_terms.label_tag }}
  ```
- If you must customise attributes of your `<input>` (which doesn't seem to be the case here), then make sure you still refer to your form's field so that the various attributes are correct:

  ```
  <input type="checkbox" name="{{ form.u_terms.html_name }}" id="{{ form.u_terms.id_for_label }}" class="some-custom-class">
  <label for="{{ form.u_terms.id_for_label }}"><span></span></label>
  ```